# Whose + article

Tags: whose

Why does '*whose*' no longer precede an article? If '*whose*' is equivalent to '*of which*', it should be allowed to, should it not ?

Comment: Examples would help here. I suspect that *which* falls into two different parts of speech.

Comment: Some of the commonest – we often think simplest – words are hardest to define. If you've come across a dictionary definition of 'whose' suggesting 'of which', it's a best attempt. But still a poor one. Here, as with most 'function words', the usage of the word is a far better way of characterising it than an attempt to 'give a definition'. (J Lawler would be proud of me.) It is a relative pronoun showing possession. See [here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-relative.htm).

Comment: As with all other possessive determiners, _whose_ in itself indicates inherent definiteness. That means that it cannot be used with articles, neither indefinite nor definite. Just like you can’t say “my a house” or “my the house”, only “my house”, you can’t say “whose a/the house?”, only “whose house?”.

Comment: @Janus Quite right. 'Whose' is far more commonly used as a determiner than as a pronoun. Whose pencil is this? v Whose is this? Replacing 'Whose is this? by 'Of whom is this?', one wonders why OP thinks articles have ever been involved at all.

Comment: Ah, I think it's the different roles of 'of which' that are adding to the confusion. 'I planted some seeds, some of which the birds ate.' Here, 'of which' is not replaceable by 'whose'. 'The bird of which the belly was biggest' is an awkward equivalent of 'The bird whose belly was biggest', and here, if one's citing 'exact replacements', 'of which the' = 'whose'. OP's dictionary was saving on ink.

Comment: Just because two words or phrases have equivalent meaning, does not mean that they necessarily have the same grammar.

Comment: Yes, The bird whose belly was biggest is what I am referring to. Long time ago ,it would have been fine to say The bird whose the belly was biggest, something clearer and apparently the missing the nowadays has no reason to happen.

Answer (score 1):

While some dictionaries will state a definition of *whose* to mean *of whom* or *of which*, it is always best to also see how that definition works, rather than looking at those words and getting confused.

- ‘**Whose** lunch box is this?’ the teacher asked.
- The children scratched their heads, wondering **whose** it was.
- Peter Johnson was a very important businessman **whose** particular attention Charlotte did not readily favour.

In these three examples, an article does **not** follow *whose* because, as Janus and Edwin have noted above, *whose* by itself is an adequate determiner for the object and any *my, the, a, this*, or *every* is not necessary to convey further ownership.

Not to be confused with *who’s*, which can be followed by an article.